# Documenting /Designing ASP.NET Web API with Swagger

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger

I have a functional Web API project. How can I retrofit it with minimal effort to a Swagger documentation/design like 
http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/

Is there a native Swagger like capability available for Web API itself?

Answer (score 13):

For the ASP.NET Web API I recommend you "[Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle)". This implementation simplifies adding Swagger to any Web API project by following simple steps. Basically, you will only have to Install the [Swashbuckle NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/) and follow some easy instructions.

Taiseer Joudeh wrote the post "[ASP.NET Web API Documentation using Swagger](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/)" about how to configure it.

Another popular implementation is [Swagger.net](https://github.com/Swagger-Net/Swagger.Net), but last change was made 2 years ago, so it seems discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [NSwag](http://nswag.org) to generate Swagger specifications and client code for existing Web API controllers... There is a Windows GUI and command line tools to integrate the tools in your build chains...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might also try Swank. Automatically generates documentation, supports XML comments, markdown, emojis, coventions, etc: http://www.mikeobrien.net/swank/